# How to display "all" the picklist values using sosl

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Iam building "where" clause,How to display "all" the picklist values using "sosl" query.Here "aircraft" is picklist.

//picklist value is not equal to "all" and record type isnot equal to "all"

```
       if((aircraftvalue !='all' && recordTypeLabel!='all'){
        Id recid = Schema.SObjectType.Document__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId(); 
        whereclause = 'WHERE Aircraft_Manufacturer__c = \''+aircraftvalue+ '\'  and  recordtype.id =\''+recid+ '\' ';
    }
```

---

```
  //picklist value not equal to null and record type="all"

  else if(aircraftvalue != null || recordTypeLabel=='all'){
       List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordtypes = Document__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();    
           for(RecordTypeInfo rt : recordtypes){
                if(rt.getName() != 'Master'){
                    op.add(rt.getRecordTypeId());

                }        
            }

        String joinedString = String.join(new List<String>(op), ',');

        //s1.replace(target, replacement
        joinedstring = joinedString.replace(',', '\',\'');

        whereclause = 'WHERE Aircraft_Manufacturer__c = \''+aircraftvalue+ '\'  and  recordtype.id in ( \''+joinedString+ '\') ';

    }
```

---

**I need answer for these two situation**

```
else if(aircraftvalue=='All' && recordType=='All'){ }
```

---

//picklist value is all and record type not equal to all

```
 else if((aircraftvalue=='All' && recordtype!='all"){ }
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. If you want to return all records regardless of the value of the picklist field, you don't need to filter on it.

Comment: ya. In that case is fine.suppose picklist values is "all"and record type isnot set to "all"...

Comment: ... then filter on the record type but not the picklist? I think it would really help if you took a step back and added some more *description* to your question - what *exactly* are you trying to do here. I for one don't follow. Also agree with @DavidSchach that I don't see how SOSL is involved here.

Comment: I have update my question how can I build my "where" clause in that situation.

Comment: I have done like this:else if(aircraftvalue=='all' && recordTypeLabel!='all'){ 
            Id recid = Schema.SObjectType.Document__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId(); 
              whereclause = 'WHERE recordtype.id =\''+recid+ '\' ';
        }is it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an apples and oranges problem.

- SOSL is for querying data.
- Picklist values are metadata.

Thus, you can't use SOSL to get picklist values. Use describe methods.

Are you trying to get all the picklist values available within a given record type? That's a different question and has already been asked here - do a search on this site. (Hint: You may need to use an Apex wrapper for the Metadata API - see Andy Fawcett's library on GitHub.) Edit: Use UI API instead of Metadata API and you'll be fine. Not sure how to access that from Apex, but it should be possible.

Comment: For the last point, as of API 42 it can be done with the [UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values_collection.htm) instead of Metadata.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(aircraftvalue=='All' && recordType=='All'){ }
```

For this use case, simply do not filter on either field. You probably do not need a `WHERE` clause at all.

```
else if((aircraftvalue=='All' && recordtype!='all"){ }
```

For this case, you need a `WHERE` filter on the record type, but not on the picklist. You already have code to generate a list of Record Type Ids to substitute into your `WHERE` clause using `RecordTypeId IN (<ids>)`.